# Add after_save callback for tag gem model to update tire index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, tags, factory-bot, tire

I have a posting model that has tags using the `rocket_tag` gem

```
class Posting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_taggable :tags

  def tag_list
    self.tags.join(",")
  end

  def tag_list=(new_tags)
    attribute_will_change!(:tag_list)
    # split into array (comma and any spaces), ignore empties
    self.tags = new_tags.split(/,[\s]*/).reject(&:empty?)
  end
```

It seems to work fine in my dev environment but when I use `FactoryGirl` to generate a posting for tests it doesn't seem to add the tags to the search index so I assume these are getting saved after the posting and so when the search index gets updated it doesn't see any saved tags so they are not searchable using `tire`.

I assume this means that I need to add an `after_save` callback to the `rocket_tag` `Tag` model to call `touch()` against the posting model but I'm not sure how to extend the model from the gem to add this extra callback and method to it.....unless something from the above could be at fault.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :posting do
    sequence(:name)  { |m| "Posting #{m} name" }
    tag_list         "tag,another,third"
    user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't work but in the end I used `FactoryGirl.create` to create the posting, visited the edit page for the posting, used capybara's `fill_in` to add the tags, `click_button "Submit"` and then I refreshed the search index.

ie I added the tags in the same way a normal webpage user would rather than trying to use FactoryGirl to set them.

Comment: Not really sure why this has been down-rated when there are currently no other answers and this is what worked for me... If there were any other answers then maybe I might have an alternative.